# appfabric New-Cache command returning 'This command is not currently allowed. Changes to the cache cluster..."

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

I have installed AppFabric Server on a Windows server machine, and successfully started the cache-cluster from the PowerShell configuration using the command `Start-CacheCluster`.  I then tried to create a new named cache using the command `New-Cache [cache_name]`, and I am getting a:

```
New-Cache : ErrorCode<ERRPS024>:SubStatus<ES0001>:This command is not currently allowed. Changes to the cache cluster configuration is restricted during a rol ling upgrade of the caching service. At line:1 char:10

+ New-Cache <<<<  indep                                                       

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Cache], DataCacheException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERRPS024,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.NewCacheCommand
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this, and am posting it just in case for any future viewers.

I had upgraded from AppFabric 1.0 (1) to AppFabric 1.1 (3).  Apparently, the cache-hosts are locked to accept only from version 1, and you need to manually upgrade them to accept connections from version 3 (AppFabric 1.1) clients.

This can be done by following the guide at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh343304(v=azure.10).aspx